# Switch case "appears" to not be working C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Essentially my switch case is not working properly in that statements for conditions I don't think are met, are executing anyway.

Example input:

```
CerseiTyrion
```

Expected output:

```
Cersei
Tyrion
```

Actual output:

```
Cersei
Tyrion
Jon
Dany
Tyrion
Jon
Dany
```

The goal of the following function is to parse some input text for an adventure game, and let the game know about some of the important information contained within the text. It then continues to use what it finds to execute code that should always run with the rest of the function if certain conditions are met.

Minimal, complete; verifiable example:

```
void HandleGameState( const std::string& text ) {

    enum Characters { 
        Cersei = 0x01, 
        Tyrion = 0x02,
        Jon    = 0x04,
        Dany   = 0x08
    };

    unsigned int mask = 1;

    switch( characterMask & mask )
    {
      case Cersei:
      {
        std::cout << "Cersei" << std::endl;
      };
      case Tyrion:
      {
        std::cout << "Tyrion" << std::endl;
      };
      case Jon:
      {
        std::cout << "Jon" << std::endl;
      };
      case Dany:
      {
        std::cout << "Dany" << std::endl;
      };
    }
}
```

Comment: Just put `break` after each case statement ends.

Comment: We usually have a `break;` after each case to make it not fall through to the next one.

Comment: Take a `break;` from GoT please :)

Comment: While your example is very helpful in illustrating your question, it is not a [MCVE]. It can be greatly reduced (EventData doesn't matter, how you find `characterMask` doesn't matter, the `#ifdef` / `#endif` dont matter). It is also not executable, therefore it can't be used to verify your question.

Comment: Would this even compile with characterMask& mask in the switch declaration? Wouldn't it see you attempting to declare a reference to a characterMask that isn't even referencing anything?

Comment: @JoeManiaci `&` in the context of the question has nothing to do with a reference, it's an operator that evaluates to the bits of each operand which are equivalent. I just tried and the code does indeed compile :)

Comment: Your `switch` statement is worthless.  The variable `characterMask` is not defined.  Also, there are only 2 values after `characterMask & 1`: 0 and 1.  Your doesn't handle `case 0`, so that leaves only `case 1`.

Comment: @SchwiftySzechuan - Doh, that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to finish your switch cases with `break` statements, otherwise code continues to the next case label.

Counter-intuitive to some people, `switch` is not glorified multi-`if` statement, but rather a glorified `goto` statement. Every case label behaves like `goto` label, and absent of `break`, the code will simply continue executing.

This is often used in cases when two different case labels need to produce the same output - instead of duplicating the code, the labels are simply put one after another. For example:

```
switch (x) {
    case 1: // fall through
    case 2: work_one_or_two(); break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Good answer for explaining the _label_ nature of `case` (a trivia question unfortunately).

Comment: Thankyou for the answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `break` behind every `case`.

The switch/case rule is easy, after a mached case, all following cases will be executed until a break; or end of switch.